# (UNITY 5) How do i Give the player control of my character once an animation is complete?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently in the middle of making an FPS game in Unity 5. I'm about to make my first cutscene and was wondering, how would I assign movement controls to the player once the cutscene has finished?

Bear in mind I may have been an idiot by making the game and the cutscene all one scene :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Animation Events](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimationEvents.html) to call a function in a script. For example, you could mark a boolean in the player controller to indicate whether the player is controllable or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Animator parameters for example take a bool `isMoving` and set it via a script and use to transition between animation states first my player is in idle state when I set `isMoving` to true it will transition to moving state 
set it false then will transition to another state
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gAFT.png)